# node js array.length not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
      conn.query('SELECT * FROM db', function(err, rows, fields){
         res.send(rows.length);
      });
});
```

when I go to `'/'` url,
I get an **error** saying:

> RangeError: Invalid status code: 2
>       at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)
>       at ServerResponse.writeHead (/var/www/html/node_modules/....

why is it happening?

I can send rows and the results are:

```
[{"id":"1", "email":"aaa@aaa.com", "nickname":"hahah"}, {"id":"2", "email":"bbb@bbb.com", "nickname":"hohoho"}]
```

`length` property is not working.

Answer (score 4):

`rows.length` is working just fine and its value is `2`. However, when you pass a number type to `res.send()` it treats it as an HTTP status code to send back in the response. `2` is not a valid HTTP status code, which is why you are getting that particular error.

If you want to send the value itself as the body of the response, you will need to explicitly convert the value to a string first. For example:

```
res.send('' + rows.length);
```

Comment: or you can use `res.status(200).send(rows.length);`

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will try that!!